# UIView on top of parentView

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a navigation view controller and I want a subview ( just a view and not a view controller) to slide on top of it when a button in the parent view is clicked. Now, the thing is when I do this:

```
[parentView addSubview:slideView];

[UIView beginAnimations]

//setting the frame for sliding

[UIView CommitAnimations]
```

the sliding view goes under the navigation bar after sliding. I would like it to slide on top of the navigation bar of the parent view. How do I achieve this?

Essentially, all I am trying to do is: replicate the iPhone Add Contact application with the only difference being; unlike me, they don't have a navigation controller on the parentView but just a navigation bar with a system add button.

Anyone!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use:

```
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:view];
```

that will slide up a view (I think) over the navigation bar.

Comment: @Clayson, Like I said, the sliding view is not a view controller but just a view. Do I have to convert this view into a viewController.view?

Comment: I don't know - I'm convinced that it works with a UIView but if not then just make your UIView into a UIViewController. A UIViewController has a view element (myViewController.view). :)

Comment: Hey Clayson, turns out, it doesn't work with UIViews. Had to convert it into viewController.view to achieve what I wanted. Got it done finally. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the view (which should be over the navigation bar) as a subview to the navigation bar.

Comment: [navigationBar addSubview:slideView];